# Sampling number in repeated measure one way ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

May I proceed with a repeated measure one way ANOVA if my subjects (individuals) doesn´t have the same number of measures? Imagine a clinical trial with 30 individuals, with *n* periods of sampling, but some individuals missed some of the sampling periods. Several packages in R are showing errors based on the *NA* values.

Comment: Could you please indicate type of measurement - eh.  Continuous data.

Comment: @subhashc.davar the measurement are continuous (velocity in different roads)

Comment: You may insert an average of given set of values.Be sure that you do not have too many missing values.

Comment: Thanks@subhashc.davar! So basically one cannot use set that contains missing values

Comment: Statistics itself especially mathematical statistics is a  science of approximation.

Comment: Perhaps R- packages  are not backed by Artificial Intelligence.  Am I distracting you ?

Comment: No no! I understand the approximation ideia but insert an average migth have influence in the results, since different individuals have different behaviours! I have done the same test in SPSS and looking at the results I have realized that, at least the mean, are done with the N of the smallest sample, i.e., if all sample have 30 trials but a sample just have 5 trials, the program only uses the same 5 individuals for the statistics.

Comment: The samples are unbalanced!!!I think  that is the correct term

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61309/discussion-between-subhash-c-davar-and-rui).

Comment: What is n period of sampling ? And what is your hypothesis that you would like to test ?